# Conditionally Scraping Domains based on keywords stored in a csv using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a list of keywords stored in a csv which I require to be searched for at different domains and scrape information.

I've tried to instruct my spider to follow them in the order of : { example1.com, example2.com, example3.com and example4.com }

The Spider only enters the next domain if it does not find a match in the previous domain. If a match for the keywords has been found in any of those domains, the next keyword from my csv is then picked next search restarts from example1.com

Importantly, I also require that particular keyword which is picked from the csv to be stored in one of the items fields.

So far my code is:

```
item = ExampleItem()
f = open("InputKeywords.csv")
csv_file = csv.reader(f)
productname_list = []
for row in csv_file:
  productname_list.append(row[1])

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
  name = "test1"
  allowed_domains = ["example1.com", "example2.com", "example3.com"]

  def start_requests(self):
    for keyword in productname_list:              
      item ["Product_Name"] = keyword  #loading the searched keyword in my output 
      request=Request("http://www.example1.com/search?noOfResults=20&keyword="+str(keyword),self.Example1)      
      yield request
      if item ["Example1"] == "No Image Found on Example1":
        request=Request("www.Example2.in/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords="+str(keyword),self.Example2)
        yield request
          if item ["Example2"] == "No Image Found on Example3":
           request=Request("http://www.Example3.com/search?noOfResults=20&keyword="+str(keyword),self.Example3):
           yield request


  def Example1(self,response): 
    sel = Selector(response)        
    result =  response.xpath("//div[@class='hoverProductImage product-image '][1]/a/@href")  #Checking if the Search Term Exists on Domain
    if result: 
      request = Request(result.extract()[0],callback=self.Example1Items) #For Parsing Information if search keyword found 
      request.meta["item"] = item
      return request
    else:
      item ["Example1"] = "No Image Found at Example1"  
      return item

  def Example1Items(self,response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    item = response.meta['item']
        item ["Example1"] = sel.xpath("//meta[@name='og_image']/@content").extract()
        return item

  def Example2(self,response):
        sel = Selector(response)    
        result=  response.xpath("//div[@class='a-row a-spacing-small'][1]/a/@href")
        if result:
          request = Request(result.extract()[0],callback=self.Example2Items)
          request.meta["item"] = item
          return request
        else:
          item ["Example2"] = "No Image Found at Example2"
          return item

 def Example2Items(self,response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        item = response.meta['item']
        item ["Example2"] = sel.xpath("//div[@class='ap_content']/div/div/div/img/@src").extract()
        return item

----CODE FOR EXAMPLE 3 and EXAMPLE 3 Items----
```

My code is far from correct but the first error I'm facing is that my keywords are not being stored in the same order as that of the input csv. 
I also am not being able to execute the logic for example2 or example 3 searches based on the not found condition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Basically I need my output which I'll be storing in a csv to be look like this:

```
{
"Keyword1", "Example1Found","","",

"Keyword2", "No Image Found at Example1","No Image Found at Example2","Example3Found",

"Keyword3", "No Image Found at Example1","Example2Found","",
}
```